# Having a simple increment-clock procedure on top of sorted by inclusive time list! Optimize netlogo code

Tags: performance, profiler, netlogo, agents, agent-based-modeling

In my simulation every tick clock value should increment by one, after resolving some of my other performance problems I have noticed this function is on top of the sorted by inclusive time list (the value is **960205 ms**):

Calls Incl T(ms) Excl T(ms) Excl/calls

40001 **960205.451**   3586.591      0.090

```
to increment-clock  
         set clock (clock + 1)
                   if clock = 48
                         [ set clock 0 ]
    end
```

According to http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/5.0/docs/profiler.html
*Inclusive time is the time from when the procedure was entered, until it finishes*

I thought this one should be straight forward and easy,

what I am doing wrong here?

I remember I used ticks before to increment the clock , I don't remember why I have changed it to the one I mentioned above, but still this should not take this much time! (the profiler inclusive time value for this one is  **599841.851 ms** which indicated following is faster than the one above:

```
to increment-clock  
         set clock (clock + 1)
                   if ticks mod 48 = 0 [set clock 0]
end
```

Calls Incl T(ms) Excl T(ms) Excl/calls

40001 **599841.851**   2943.394      0.074

Thanks.
Marzy

Comment: I have ran experiments with the same random seed with changing the to increment-clock procedures and printed the profile results. I know this might not be a good way to measure performance of two functions but I think it might be good for choosing one function among two similar functions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That has to be a bug in the profiler extension. At least, I can't think of another explanation. (Well, are you calling `profiler:reset` between runs...?)

I tried this just now:

```
extensions [profiler]

globals [clock]

to increment-clock  
         set clock (clock + 1)
                   if clock = 48
                         [ set clock 0 ]
    end

to test
  profiler:reset
  profiler:start
  repeat 1000000 [ increment-clock ]
  profiler:stop
  print profiler:report
end
```

and I get:

```
observer> test
BEGIN PROFILING DUMP
Sorted by Exclusive Time
Name                               Calls Incl T(ms) Excl T(ms) Excl/calls
INCREMENT-CLOCK                  1000000   1176.245   1176.245      0.001

Sorted by Inclusive Time
INCREMENT-CLOCK                  1000000   1176.245   1176.245      0.001

Sorted by Number of Calls
INCREMENT-CLOCK                  1000000   1176.245   1176.245      0.001
END PROFILING DUMP
```

which seems much more reasonable.

You can report the bug at https://github.com/NetLogo/NetLogo/issues or bugs@ccl.northwestern.edu.

Comment: I call this method in my Go procedure and I did not check it individually (like yours), and yes I reset profiler between runs, it must be a bug because it's still on top of my list even when I changed many other things!